# Building virtual desktop

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to write an application to serve as the virtual desktop. The main objective of the application is the ability to put shortcuts to installed applications. Therefore, there are several tasks to be performed, for which I need suggestions:

1. Calling activity "All Applications" to indicate the application you want to create a shortcut
2. Reading, which pointed to an application user (or that did not indicate anything)
3. Reading the application icon specified by the user
4. Ability to run the application by indicating the shortcut

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple,

1. Use a `GridLayout` or `TableLayout` for listing icons
2. Use `PackageManager` to get all installed applications' information.
3. `PackageManager` returns application' image
4. `PackageManager` returns the `Intent` to execute that application
5. For desktop?, change top level parent layout background image.